# Python: List of Dictionaries, within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

Right now I have a list of dictionaries e.g.

```
x = [{ '1':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':'b'},  
     { '1':1, '2':3, '4':'d'},
     ......]
```

I also have a second list of dictionaries e.g.

```
y = [{'a':'a', 'b':'b'}, 
     {'f':'f', 'h':'i', 'o':'p'},
     {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d'},
     .....]
```

Some of the data within the second dictionary is a subsection of the initial list, how I can append the dictionary with a list of elements from the second dictionary. (e.g. if it has the value b at key b.)

```
Result    
    x = [{ '1':1, '2':2, '3':3, 4:[{'a':'a', 'b':'b'},
                                   {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d'}]},
         { '1':1, '2':3, '4':'d'}
         ......]
```

I have created a loop to go through and find the required elements, but I have been unable to add a single dictionary, but unable to add a list of them.

I have tried to use `x.append[1]['4'] = y[1]` or looped through adding them, but I cannot get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

My attempt to simplify might of made it more awkward. Edited samples of the dictionaries provided below to clear things up. Thank you for the answers, I'm trying to get them to work, this is for clarification.

```
balance = [{'Currency': 'ADA', 'Balance': 30},  
           {'Currency': 'SC', 'Balance': 200.2}
           .....]
```

Second

```
history = [{'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 13.2, 'PricePerUnit': 5}, 
           {'XC': 'NAV', 'Quantity': 39.1, 'PricePerUnit': 25}, 
           {'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 63.49, 'PricePerUnit': 0.1}
           ....]
```

After first iteration it would be

```
Result   
balance = [{'Currency': 'ADA', 'Balance': 30, 'History':
                           [{'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 13.2, 'PricePerUnit': 5},
                            {'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 63.49, 'PricePerUnit': 0.1}]},
           {'Currency': 'SC', 'Balance': 200.2}
           .....]
```

---

## Solution

For the first example it is done with:

```
x[1]['4'].append(y[2])
```

The task I was trying to do, the answer without iteration is:

```
balance[0]['History'].append(history[0])
balance[0]['History'].append(history[2])
```

Thanks to both Faibbus and Rakesh for their solutions!

Comment: Can you put some expect result here ?

Comment: The third section is the expected results. I will change it to highlight it.

Comment: It should be `x[1]['4'] = [y[0]]` to create a list, and then `x[1]['4'].append(y[2])` to add all the other elements.

Comment: I only seen this commend Faibbus, ``x[1]['4'].append(y[2])`` is exactly what I have been looking for, I tried something like that but I must of gotten the syntax wrong. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure about what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you want to:

```
first_list = [{ 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:'b'},  
              {1:1, 2:3, 4:'d'},]
second_list = [{'a':'a', 'b':'b'}, 
               {'f':'f', 'h':'i', 'o':'p'},
               {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d'},]

# Loop through all dictionaries:
for dictionary in first_list:
    # Loop through all values
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value == 'b':
            # find all dictionaries matching you criteria
            dicts = [d for d in second_list if d.get('b') == 'b']
            if dicts:
                # if there are dictionaries matching your criteria,
                #   replace the value with list of dictionaries
                dictionary[key] = dicts

print first_list
```

Will output:

```
[{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4:[{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'},
                       {'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b', 'd': 'd'}]},
 {1: 1, 2: 3, 4: 'd'}]
```

In case you are using python3 :

```
first_list = [{ 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:'b'},  
              {1:1, 2:3, 4:'d'},]
second_list = [{'a':'a', 'b':'b'}, 
               {'f':'f', 'h':'i', 'o':'p'},
               {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d'},]

# Loop through all dictionaries:
for dictionary in first_list:
    # Loop through all values
    for key, value in list(dictionary.items()):
        if value == 'b':
            # find all dictionaries matching you criteria
            dicts = [d for d in second_list if d.get('b') == 'b']
            # Or you might want to remove the test on value, and
            #   replace 'b' by value in the previous line
            if dicts:
                # if there are dictionaries matching your criteria,
                #   replace the value with list of dictionaries
                dictionary[key] = dicts

print (first_list)
```

To work with your latest edit, you can do :

```
balance = [{'Currency': 'ADA', 'Balance': 30},  
           {'Currency': 'SC', 'Balance': 200.2}
           ]


history = [{'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 13.2, 'PricePerUnit': 5}, 
           {'XC': 'NAV', 'Quantity': 39.1, 'PricePerUnit': 25}, 
           {'XC': 'ADA', 'Quantity': 63.49, 'PricePerUnit': 0.1}
           ]
# reorganize history:
new_history = {}
for record in history:
    if not record['XC'] in new_history:
        new_history[record['XC']] = []
    new_history[record['XC']].append(record)
# Update balance to include history:
for account in balance:
    if account['Currency'] in new_history:
        account['history'] = new_history[account['Currency']]

print(balance)
```

Leading to

```
[{'Currency': 'ADA', 'Balance': 30, 'history': [{'XC': 'ADA', 'PricePerUnit': 5, 'Quantity': 13.2},
                                                {'XC': 'ADA', 'PricePerUnit': 0.1, 'Quantity': 63.49}]},
 {'Currency': 'SC', 'Balance': 200.2}]
```

Comment: You may not do: `dictionary[key] = dicts` within a Loop if you are looping through `dictionary` List itself.....

Comment: I am looping through `dictionnary.items()`, which is a list in python2.7.

Comment: I keep getting 'dict' `object has no attribute 'iteritems'` i have been trying it from examples I seen on other pages.

Comment: And you get an error when doing `print 'something'` ? Because you must be using python3

Comment: Hi Faibbus, I can copy and paste your code and it works great. I'm trying to translate it into my little project. Having a few problems, it might take me a while :)

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [{ 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:'b'}, {1:1, 2:3, 4:'d'}]

B =[{'a':'a', 'b':'b'}, 
 {'f':'f', 'h':'i', 'o':'p'},
 {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d'}]


for i in A:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        for j in B:
            if v in j.values():
                if not isinstance(i[k], list):
                    i[k] = [j]
                else:
                    i[k].append(j)


print A
```

**Result:**

```
[{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: [{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b', 'd': 'd'}]}, {1: 1, 2: 3, 4: [{'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b', 'd': 'd'}]}]
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
What library are you getting the `interitems` from?

Comment: `iteritems`, and this is a standard method on dictionaries in python2.7 that is equivalent to `items` in python 3

Comment: Sorry I posed this in the wrong threat
 
I keep getting `'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` i have been trying it from examples I seen on other pages.

Comment: Like I said, Rakesh assumed you were using python2.7, but replace `iteritems` with `items`, and it will work for python3.